# Magic: the Gathering - The Ideal Creature

Tags: calculation-puzzle, magic-the-gathering

You and your friend John both enjoy Magic the Gathering, but you've gotten into an argument over which creature is the best.  The two of you agree that the only fair way to settle this is to see how good each creature is individually.  You proceed to build decks consisting of 59 basic lands and the one creature under consideration, and see how quickly you can kill an opponent whose deck consists of 60 basic lands.

The best creature *according to the two of you* is the one that can win this arrangement on the earliest turn possible (and, as tiebreaker, deal the most damage to the opponent).  You may stack your hand and deck however you like at the start of the game.

**After investigating [all creatures legal in Vintage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&type=+[%22Creature%22]&format=+[%22Vintage%22]), which do you and John conclude is the best?**

*Example: A deck consisting of [Brushstrider](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=416934) and 59 basic forests can deal 21 damage by turn nine.*

Comment: Do poison counters count here?

Comment: I am familiar with such turn-based card games, although not with this particular one. Should not this question be narrowed down to a selection of handful of well-defined cards (e.g. the *ten best*) of which we should decide which one is *the* best? How many distinct cards are there actually, to inspect?

Comment: Being familiar with this card game, this question seems rather open-ended. It would be prudent to address strategies such as whether your creature's attack goes unblocked, alternative win conditions, etc., and would become a question of whether the "best" creature is only best in the circumstance that your opponent does not provide the appropriate counter to your strategy.

Comment: If we actually cared about the real best creature, yes, it would be open ended.  That's why you and John have come up with a highly restricted format, in which your opponent's deck contains no blockers or interaction.  Alternative win conditions are fine, provided the card can trigger them on its own.

Comment: So, as clarification, Tideforce Elemental could not be considered a best creature because its effect of tap-locking the opponent is considered interaction?

Comment: By our measuring stick, Tideforce Elemental can be cast on turn 3, and (regardless of how you tap or untap it) may only attack once per turn.  Thus it kills on turn 13, which makes it worse than our Brushstrider example.

Comment: I brought it up specifically for the purpose of discussing the interaction stipulation

Comment: I guess the better way for me to phrase my question is, are you and John playing against each other? Or are you playing solitaire against a punching bag that has no means of defending itself and/or trying to win against you in the same manner?

Comment: Solitaire.  There is one creature between your two decks combined.  But if your creature depends on the opponent's hand or deck, you may assume it consists entirely of basic lands.

Comment: It might be better to make explicit, that you can assume the creature card is in your first hand?

Comment: Does this question require prior experience in *Magic: The Gathering*?

Comment: Yes, this question requires prior experience to understand when you can get a creature onto the field in addition to any effect chaining involved.  This isn't so much a puzzle as MtG experimentation.  Additionally, the argument won't be resolved because this only measures raw attack ability, negating all of it's other weaknesses or the plethora of cards that can remove it from the field.

Comment: 1) Is "Life lost" equivalent to damage in this context? In MtG rules, "Target player loses x life" and "Deal x damage to target player" aren't the same thing, only the latter is actual damage, but I figured this might be a different case.  2) How does the dummy opponent handle choice, like "Your opponent chooses one" or being allowed to pay mana to cancel an effect et cetera. Chance, most beneficial choice, least beneficial choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new challenger appears!

> [Flailing Soldier](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=19602)

Turn 1: play the creature. Can't attack yet.

Turn 2: While attacking, pay 2 to pump up to 4/4. 4 damage. BUT WAIT! Our opponent went first, and pays 3, to make it a 7/7.

Turn 3: While attacking, pay 3 to pump up to 5/5. Our opponent pays 4, making it a 9/9.

Turn 4: While attacking, pay 4 to pump up to 6/6. Our opponent pays 5, pumping it up to 11/11.

Total damage: 27. Turn 4.
Can not POSSIBLY get faster.

(and technically it's possible)

> Even though if someone tried this against you you could kill it immediately.

Thus, this creature takes the crown for being the absolute best, and the absolute worst creature in Magic: the Gathering.

Comment: turn 4 on the draw is slower than on the play, which gets 24 on turn 4, if opponent help is legal, that is.

Comment: Questionable whether "earliest turn" means YOUR turn, or all turns, but that's a fair note.

Comment: Oooh, I like it.  I had considered that card tied for second with your other answer, but didn't think about the opponent paying as well!  Very nice.  24 on the play would be faster, though still (at least) second best.

Comment: What turn does your #1 answer kill on? I can't visualize anything costing 1 or 2 mana and having time to ramp up faster than this.

Comment: Orcish Captain follows the same pattern and kills on the same turn but does not deal as much damage. It, however, requires you to win 9 coin tosses in a row, which is highly unlikely.

Comment: Whoops, my apologies - while my other solution works in a more general game, it does *not* fit given the specific restrictions I gave.  For example, if you added a Gitaxian Probe to your deck, it would be possible to find a creature that deals twice as much damage as this answer can by turn 4.  But that's fine - this answer is more amusing any way!

Comment: Ahh, I see. What did you have in mind originally? I was considering a few really cool options that were negated by the fact that you had to use basic lands only. Without that restriction, Vampire Hexmage wins by quite a bit, enabling Marit Lage.

Comment: I think what he was thinking of is [Countryside Crusher](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370544) but that makes you lose on your Draw step.

Comment: I wanna say there was a red/blue creature that exiled spells you were playing to buff itself, might have been what they were going for.

Answer (score 6):

> [Student of Warfare](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=193598)

22 Damage, turn 5 on the play.

Turn 1: 
play the creature, it can't attack yet.

Turn 2:
level 2, attack for 3 damage.

Turn 3:
Level 5, attack for 3 damage.

Turn 4: 
Level 9, attack for 8 damage. (at this point level no longer means anything)

Turn 5: 
Level 14, attack for 8 damage.

22 damage total.

Comment: I thought about deleting this answer, but it's still probably helpful to show the thought process that went into getting to where I got. If you're interested in seeing other contenders, check out Primordial Ooze, Mayor of Avabruck, and Figure of Destiny. All of them are notorious for being explosive starts to games, without committing more than a single card to the table.

Answer (score 5):

The card

> [Pack Rat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=253624)

can deal a total of 20 damage on Turn 5's combat damage step on the play, assuming you start with it in your opening hand. Interestingly enough, in the event you're playing commander, it can deal 44 damage on Turn 6's combat damage step.

> **Turn 2:** Play Pack Rat;
> **Turn 3:** Activate its ability before the combat step to make a copy of Pack Rat, then attack with the original Pack Rat, dealing *2 damage* (1 attacker with 2 power);
> **Turn 4:** Activate its ability before the combat step to make a second copy of Pack Rat, then attack with the original and the first copy, dealing *6 damage* (2 attackers with 3 power each);
> **Turn 5:** Activate its ability before the combat step to make a third copy of Pack Rat, then attack with the original and the first two copies, dealing *12 damage* (3 attackers with 4 power each).

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to increase the total damage done by using the abilities of the tokens too? Or is that illegal?

Comment: @McFry it costs a total of 3 mana to activate the ability, so the first turn you could use it a second time, mana-wise is turn 6.

Comment: Okay, I see. So it is only allowed to place 1 land card per turn?

Comment: @McFry Correct, players may only play one land per turn unless a card's effect changes that rule (such as the card Exploration).

Comment: Just slightly edges out Figure of Destiny, which is 22 damage on turn 6. And yes, I remember losing games to that because that little bastard was always growing one turn too fast for my removal.  I think the only possible contenders to beat the rat are the level up guys and Ashling the Pilgrim, but they're nowhere near the exponential growth of the rat.

Comment: Scratch that, I found one.

Answer (score 3):

An amusing, but perhaps not entirely satisfying, yet in my opinion entirely within the wording of the original question answer:

> Similarly to the way [fool's mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool's_mate) is technically the fastest checkmate in chess, the creature Menacing Ogre can inflict 24 'damage' on turn 5 (emphasis **can**, as per the original wording). Both players choose 19, then attack for 5.

Another 'outside the box' answer I can think of that is worse than the other answers presented, but is still amusing:

> Lupine Prototype can inflict 20 damage on turn 6 after mulliganing down appropriately to start the game to achieve hellbent.

Comment: Not bad - I like the creativity!  As it happens, you can do even better than 24 damage on turn 5, so we don't need to decide whether that's within the rules.

Comment: I would call that 43 damage. Damage to yourself is still damage!

Comment: Alternatively, you can clarify the puzzle further and say that paying life, or loss of life, does not count as damage (this is consistent with the game's rules), so it doesn't count here.

Answer (score -1):

Please consider this an outside the box answer...

All creatures [legal in Vintage](http://magic.wizards.com/en/game-info/gameplay/rules-and-formats/banned-restricted), hey?

I'm thinking

> [Infernal Spawn of Evil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9779)

which will deal 22 damage by turn 4, 1 from your hand on the first turn, and 7 on each successive turn once summoned, if playing mana flow - and 24 damage by turn 7 if mana restricted after first turn.

Of course, if you're willing to bend just a tad then

> [BFM](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=9780)

Which can deal 99 damage as early as turn 2 playing mana flow, or by either turn 6 or 11 depending on mana restriction after the first turn.  (however, this does require either one less land in your deck, or a deck of 61, since it is one creature on two cards)

I suppose it should be noted the whole expansion is generally not playable except in rather casual games (which, forgive, this solitaire version *does* seem to be)... I am taking the loophole of the expansion not appearing on the banned list, and it also specifying "any" cards not on that list are allowed :D

Comment: What is mana flow?

Comment: @Kruga - a specific play style, very common where/when I was first playing, that had lands being put down for free, and allowed players to draw their hands back up to strength afterwards... the idea was that it encouraged a quick and lively game, since you spent more time using playables rather than waiting for mana to be drawn (the skill was in using those playables, and deck building around the flow).  Standard rules otherwise were lands were free on the first turn, and one-per-turn only after that.

Comment: Silver-bordered cards, such as those from Unglued and Unhinged, are not vintage-legal.  Although the site you linked to doesn't mention that, the card itself states that it is only legal in the "Un-Sets" format, which is casual only.